# incorporating co* library into async code

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, co

I am confused as to how to use the `co` package to make my following async code more readable
https://www.npmjs.com/package/co

```
async.each(longList, function(address, callback) {

  googleMapsClient.geocode({
    address: address
    }, function(err, response) {

      // send the response to database
      http.request(options, function(res) {

        // now process the next address
        callback();
      });

   }

}, function(err) {
   if (err) throw err;
}
```

I also welcome any other style of coding the above, whatever mades the code cleaner

Comment: You should go for `async`/`await` right away. Don't bother with `co` any more.

Comment: You said you are confused - with what? Did you try anything?